# How to use DBMS_PROFILER in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: performance, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to analyze the procedure code line-by-line to find out the performance bottleneck. Database used is Oracle 11g Express. How to use **DBMS_PROFILER** in Oracle SQL Developer ?

Comment: Check the following link. It may help you https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:458240723799

Comment: @Avrajit Roy: The link you suggested doesn't explain about the usage of DBMS_PROFILER in SQL Developer.